# Java: when to use generics method and when explicit method

Tags: java, generics

Lets suppose we have 10 types of Car:Bmw, Renault etc. And we have Repo. So there are two ways for developing API of Repo:

The first way:

```
class Repo{
  public <T extends Car> T getCarByType(Class<T> clazz){..}
}
```

The second way:

```
class Repo{
   public Bmw getBmw(){..}
   public Reno getRenault(){..}
   ...
}
```

Firstly I thought that I should follow the first way as it lets write less code and -> it is better for supporting. And besides, I thought that if I have 20 types of car the first way is obvious advantage (less code).

However, as the number of car is growing - you start to forget what car you have. When you follow the second way - you have clear API of the repo and the types.

So,could anyone explain when to use which method?

Comment: How about `public Car getCar()`? That would encourage callers to be agnostic of the car type, making the code more extensible to future car types.

Comment: This is not really a good SO question as it doesn't really contain a specifically answerable programming question, at least, as currently stated. Also it's spelled 'Renault'.

Comment: @njzk2 https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suzuki_Reno, perhaps? (More likely a misspelling of Renault, though).

Comment: I don't think the make of a car is sufficient to justify polymorphism. You can probably have a `Car` class, with an enum for the make. And in your repo, a list or map of cars that you can search to return those of a certain brand, model, year, color, ...

Answer (score 2):

The first way will produce less duplicate code. But if you want to model the types of cars, you could use an enum

```
enum Cars {
  BMW(Bmw.class),
  RENO(Reno.class)
  ;

  Class<? extends Car> type;

  Cars(Class<? extends Car> type){
    this.type = type;
  }

  Class<? extends Car> getType() {
    return type;
  }

}
```

And the access the car using this enum

```
public <T extends Car> T getCarByType(Cars car){
  Class<T> type = car.getType();
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First if your cars aren't so different you may use only one class Car that will have a type property which will allow you to make difference between cars type, however if you wan't to continue with your solution I think you may use both of the ways, you can create a generic Repo which will have all code used to get Data then you can make on top of it a specific layer that will expose methods to retrieve each car by it's type

Generic Repo

```
class Repo{
  public <T extends Car> T getCarByType(Class<T> clazz){..}
}
```

RepoFacade

```
class RepoFacade{
   public Bmw getBmw(){
       Repo<Bmw> = new Repo<>();
       return repo.getCarByType(BMW.class);
   }
   public Reno getReno(){..}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would go with something simpler. No polymorphism based on brand, because it is just a label, it does not add any behavior:

```
public class Car {
    public enum Make { BMW, ... };

    public Make make;
    public Color color;
    public int year;
    // Cars have other properties, I suppose
}

public class Repo {
    private List<Car> cars = new ArrayList<Car>;

    // This could also return a list of all cars of that model, 
    // because there is no reason to have exactly one of each make.
    @Nullable
    public Car findByMake(Car.Make make) {
        for (Car car : cars) {
            if (car.make == make) {
                return car;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```